# How to select rows that are equal to an item in a list in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am working with a data frame that has observations from various countries. I only want to choose countries that are in a list that I determined.

```
 Country.Name     Country.Code     Indicator.Name               Indicator.Code       year     fert
1        Aruba          ABW Fertility rate, total (births per woman) SP.DYN.TFRT.IN X1960 4.820000
2  Afghanistan          AFG Fertility rate, total (births per woman) SP.DYN.TFRT.IN X1960 7.450000
3       Angola          AGO Fertility rate, total (births per woman) SP.DYN.TFRT.IN X1960 7.478000
4      Albania          ALB Fertility rate, total (births per woman) SP.DYN.TFRT.IN X1960 6.489000
5      Andorra          AND Fertility rate, total (births per woman) SP.DYN.TFRT.IN X1960       NA
6   Arab World          ARB Fertility rate, total (births per woman) SP.DYN.TFRT.IN X1960 6.948747
.....
```

For instance I only need observations that are in this list c('Aruba', 'Albania' 'Germany')

I have tried this but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
d_f <- read.csv('fertility_rate.csv') %>%
  gather(year, fertility, X1960:X2017)
d_fer <- d_f[d_f$Country.Name %in% selected_countries,]
```

Here is a detailed code:

```
pupil_ratio <- read.csv('pupil_ratio.csv')  #this data has all the countries I want
countries <-as.vector(pupil_ratio$Country.Name) #I convert it to a vector

d_f <- read.csv('fertility_rate.csv') %>%
  gather(year, fert, X1960:X2017)
d_fer <- d_f[d_f$Country.Name %in% countries,]
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Can you share a reproducible example? `data[data$country %in% country_sub, ]` this code should work..

Comment: Like @RLave says, there is no need for `gather`, it's straightforward.

Comment: What's the error message saying or are you getting empty result? Also, check the data types of `Country.Name` and `countries` are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi its simple just do indexing as below

```
d_fer <- d_f[(d_f$Country.Name %in% c('Aruba', 'Albania' 'Germany')),]
```

or

```
dataframe[c('Aruba', 'Albania' 'Germany'),]
```

hope it will work.

Comment: `dataframe[c('Aruba', 'Albania' 'Germany'),]` won't work if you don't specify the column..

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::filter()` should work fine:

```
d_f <- read.csv('fertility_rate.csv') %>%
  gather(year, fert, X1960:X2017) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Country.Name %in% countries) # only select countries which are in countries
```